# Align dropdown menu to the absolute right of the button despite the parent container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have a navigation menu built using bootstrap. The menu is filled with buttons that introduce drop down menus once clicked.

Here is the navigation menu:

[image: Navigation Menu]

How can I change the following code to align the dropdown menus to the absolute right (floating right) of the selected button. Despite being contained by the parent div.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="f_profile_add col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 np">
            <nav>
                <ul class="list-unstyled nm">
                    <li>

                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button id="btn-add-trybe" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg rmr pbpad dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</div>
```

And here is what to happen when a button is clicked:

[image: dropdown floating outside of parent div]

Can you offer me a solution?

Thanks

**Update**

The code that got me the result is as follows:

```
.absolute-right-dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 74px;
    /* Note opposite values */
    right: -20rem;
    width: 20rem;
}
```

I added this to the dropdown-menu. Resulting in the following:

[image: final working code image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with CSS absolute-positioning on your .dropdown-menu, as in the code below.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bstv23sr/) for demo.

```
.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    /* Note opposite values */
    right: -20rem;
    width: 20rem;
}
```

### Notes

1. In Bootstrap 3, class .dropdown already has `position:relative;`, and .dropdown-menu is normally a descendant of .dropdown, so you can absolute-position the .dropdown-menu based on its .dropdown.
2. When you specify the width of .dropdown-menu, be sure that your specified width is not less than the min-width that will be determined by the menu's content (e.g. in this example, 10rem is too thin).
   The `width` and `right` styles of .dropdown-menu should be equal and opposite values.

Comment: @sgsinger The right: -20rem; only adds padding to the dropdown-menu's container. Oddly. But when I add left: 60px; to the styling, it positions the dropdown-menu perfectly. Thanks for replying with a solution. Really appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome :) What do you mean by the "dropdown-menu's container"? Please update the HTML code and/or show me with a JSFiddle.

Comment: Please see updated question for the css added to get the result :)